# Connecting Raspberry Pi 3 to android over ADB failure

Tags: linux, android, raspberry-pi, adb

Currently I'm trying to connect a Raspberry PI 3 to an android tablet over `adb`. Used to work for quite sometime and now it doesn't.

If i do a `lsusb`, the device appears however `adb devices -l` shows nothing. I switched to a WiFi connection and it works however I need it to work over usb rather than WiFi.

Checking dmesg i can see the following, seems like the usb driver is flickering:

```
systemd-udevd[5786]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/mtp-probe' 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5 1 104': No such file or directory
[ 1382.614975] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 117
[ 1382.846544] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 118 using dwc_otg
[ 1382.947474] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=1bbb, idProduct=201d
[ 1382.947506] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
```

Also, when I do a `udevadm monitor`, I can see the device being added and removed repeatedly.

Is this something any of you encountered before?

[This is related](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144966/how-do-i-get-my-device-detected-by-adb-on-linux), but it didn't solve my problem.